# How to prevent from entering decimals and negatives in the Ext textfield-- Extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a textfield that is accepting large input numbers. My issue is if I use 
`Ext.form.NumerField({})` the large numbers gets converted into `1e` notation and hence I'm unable to fix this with `toFixed()`. Hence I switched to using `Ext.form.TextField({})`. However with textfield I want to prevent user from entering decimal numbers, negative numbers and allow only numeric fields.
For only numeric I can use regex:
var regex = `/[0-9.]/,`. // will only allow numeric values
But I'm not sure how can I get all the above conditions(no decimals and no negative) in the regex.

any help on regex will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just validate the input, use the following regex:

```
/^\d+$/
```

but, if you prevent typing, add this on the text field:

```
    enableKeyEvents:true,
    listeners:{
            keydown : function(t,e) {
            var code = e.browserEvent.keyCode;
            console.log(code);     
            if ((code < 48 || code > 57) &&(code !== 8)){
                e.stopEvent();
            }
        }
    },
```